# Java 8 Pattern Matching?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, matching

Will Java 8 support pattern matching like Scala and other functional programs do? I'm putting a presentation together of Java 8's Lambda features. I can't find anything on this particular Functional-programming concept.

I remember what got me interested in functional programming was the quicksort implementation, especially compared to imperative programming's implementation.

Comment: No, it won't support anything like that.

Comment: Pattern matching has nothing to do with functional programming. It is nothing but a coincidence that it is mostly available in the functional languages.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suppose you are not talking about pattern matching in the sense of applying a regular expression on a string, but as [applied in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html). For instance using wildcards:

```
head (x:_)  = x
tail (_:xs) = xs
```

Java 8 will not support that natively, with Lambda expression there are, however, ways to do so, like this for computing the factorial:

```
public static int fact(int n) {
     return ((Integer) new PatternMatching(
          inCaseOf(0, _ -> 1),
          otherwise(  _ -> n * fact(n - 1))
     ).matchFor(n));
}
```

How to implement that you will find more information in this blog post: [Towards Pattern Matching in Java](http://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/towards-pattern-matching-in-java/).

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to implement pattern matching as a library in Java 8 (taking advantage of lambda expressions), but unfortunately we will still be missing the compiler exhaustiveness check that languages such as Haskell or Scala have.

[Cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) has a powerful [Pattern Matching](http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-aol/simple-react//user-guide/pattern-matching.adoc)  module, which offers both structural pattern matching for Java 8, and pattern matching via guards.

It provides a when / then / otherwise DSL and matching, including deconstruction is based on standard Java Predicates (so matching can be used to filter a Stream for example).

### Matching by guards

For matching via guards we use whenGuard /  then / otherwise to clearly show the case is driving the test and not the structure of the Object under test.

e.g. For guard based matching, If we implement a Case class that implements the Matchable interface

```
 static class MyCase  implements Matchable{ int a; int b; int c;}
```

(btw, Lombok can come in very handy for creating sealed case class hierarchies)

We can match on it's internal values (recursively if neccessary, or by type among various other options).

```
  import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.otherwise;
  import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.whenGuard;

  new MyCase(1,2,3).matches(c->c.is(whenGuard(1,2,3)).then("hello"),
                               .is(whenGuard(4,5,6)).then("goodbye")
                               ,otherwise("goodbye")
                           );
```

If we have an Object that doesn't implement [Matchable][3], we can coerce it to Matchable anyway, our code would become

```
Matchable.ofDecomposable(()->new MyCase(1,2,3)))
         .matches(c->c.is(whenGuard(1,2,3)).then("hello"),
                      .is(whenGuard(4,5,6)).then("goodbye")
                      ,otherwise("hello"));
```

If we don't care about one of the values we can use wildcards

```
new MyCase(1,2,3).matches(c->c.is(whenGuard(1,__,3)).then("hello"),
                              .is(whenGuard(4,__,6)).then("goodbye")
                              ,otherwise("hello)
                           );
```

Or recursively de-structure a nested set of classes

```
Matchable.of(new NestedCase(1,2,new NestedCase(3,4,null)))
                .matches(c->c.is(whenGuard(1,__,has(3,4,__)).then("2")
                 ,otherwise("default");
```

Where NestedCase looks something like this -

```
class NestedCase implemends Decomposable { int a; int b; NestedCase c; }
```

Users can also compose pattern matching expressions using hamcrest

```
 import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.otherwise;
 import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.then;
 import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.when;

 Matchable.of(Arrays.asList(1,2,3))
                .matches(c->c.is(when(equalTo(1),any(Integer.class),equalTo(4)))
                        .then("2"),otherwise("default"));
```

### Structual pattern matching

We can also match on the exact structure of the Object being tested. That is rather than use if / then tests to see if the structure happens to match our cases, we can have the compiler ensure that our cases match the structure of the provided Objects. The DSL to do this is almost identical as per guard based matching, but we use when / then / otherwise to clearly show the Objects structure drives the test cases and not vice versa.

```
  import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.otherwise;
  import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.then;
  import static com.aol.cyclops.control.Matchable.when;

  String result =  new Customer("test",new Address(10,"hello","my city"))
                            .match()
                            .on$_2()
                            .matches(c->c.is(when(decons(when(10,"hello","my city"))),then("hello")), otherwise("miss")).get();

  //"hello"
```

Structurally matching on an Address Object extracted from a customer. Where the Customer and Address classes look this this

```
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Address{
    int house;
    String street;
    String city;

    public MTuple3<Integer,String,String> match(){
        return Matchable.from(()->house,()->street,()->city);
    }
}
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Customer{
    String name;
    Address address;
    public MTuple2<String,MTuple3<Integer,String,String>> match(){
        return Matchable.from(()->name,()->Maybe.ofNullable(address).map(a->a.match()).orElseGet(()->null));
    }
}
```

cyclops-react provides a [Matchables](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/cyclops-react/1.0.0-RC1/com/aol/cyclops/Matchables.html) class which allows structural pattern matching against common JDK types.

Comment: [This link](http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-aol/simple-react//user-guide/pattern-matching.adoc) in this answer seems to be broken. Is the documentation for pattern-matching available elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I am aware that this question has already been answered, furthermore I am new to functional programming but, after much hesitation, I finally decided to get invloved in this discussion to have feedback on what follows.

I would suggest the (too ?) simple implementation below. It is slightly different from the (nice) article cited in the accepted answer ; but in my (short) experience, it was a bit more flexible to use and easy to maintain (which is of course also a matter of taste).

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

final class Test
{
    public static final Function<Integer, Integer> fact = new Match<Integer>()
            .caseOf( i -> i == 0, i -> 1 )
            .otherwise( i -> i * Test.fact.apply(i - 1) );

    public static final Function<Object, String> dummy = new Match<Object>()
            .caseOf( i -> i.equals(42), i -> "forty-two" )
            .caseOf( i -> i instanceof Integer, i -> "Integer : " + i.toString() )
            .caseOf( i -> i.equals("world"), i -> "Hello " + i.toString() )
            .otherwise( i -> "got this : " + i.toString() );

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("factorial : " + fact.apply(6));
        System.out.println("dummy : " + dummy.apply(42));
        System.out.println("dummy : " + dummy.apply(6));
        System.out.println("dummy : " + dummy.apply("world"));
        System.out.println("dummy : " + dummy.apply("does not match"));
    }
}

final class Match<T>
{
    public <U> CaseOf<U> caseOf(Predicate<T> cond, Function<T, U> map)
    {
        return this.new CaseOf<U>(cond, map, Optional.empty());
    }

    class CaseOf<U> implements Function<T, Optional<U>>
    {
        private Predicate<T> cond;
        private Function<T, U> map;
        private Optional<CaseOf<U>> previous;

        CaseOf(Predicate<T> cond, Function<T, U> map, Optional<CaseOf<U>> previous)
        {
          this.cond = cond;
          this.map = map;
          this.previous = previous;
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<U> apply(T value)
        {
            Optional<U> r = previous.flatMap( p -> p.apply(value) );
            return r.isPresent() || !cond.test(value) ? r
                : Optional.of( this.map.apply(value) );
        }

        public CaseOf<U> caseOf(Predicate<T> cond, Function<T, U> map)
        {
          return new CaseOf<U>(cond, map, Optional.of(this));
        }

        public Function<T,U> otherwise(Function<T, U> map)
        {
            return value -> this.apply(value)
                .orElseGet( () -> map.apply(value) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach better than command pattern using a map, and much much better than procedural if else if ..else or the imperative swich statement. This should be part of the jvm native interfaces and proffessors in college should teach java using this feature

Comment: from which API this `Match` class belongs?

Answer (score 0):

[Derive4J](https://github.com/derive4j/derive4j) is a library aiming at supporting near-native support for sum types and structural pattern matching for java (and even more).
Taking a small calculator DSL as an example, with Derive4J you are able to write the following code:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.derive4j.Data;
import static org.derive4j.exemple.Expressions.*;

@Data
public abstract class Expression {

    interface Cases<R> {
        R Const(Integer value);
        R Add(Expression left, Expression right);
        R Mult(Expression left, Expression right);
        R Neg(Expression expr);
    }

    public abstract <R> R match(Cases<R> cases);

    private static Function<Expression, Integer> eval = Expressions
        .match()
            .Const(value        -> value)
            .Add((left, right)  -> eval(left) + eval(right))
            .Mult((left, right) -> eval(left) * eval(right))
            .Neg(expr           -> -eval(expr));

    public static Integer eval(Expression expression) {
        return eval.apply(expression);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expression expr = Add(Const(1), Mult(Const(2), Mult(Const(3), Const(3))));
        System.out.println(eval(expr)); // (1+(2*(3*3))) = 19
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JMPL](https://github.com/klappdev/jpml) is simple java library, which could emulate some of the features pattern matching, using Java 8 features.

```
   matches(data).as(
      new Person("man"),    () ->  System.out.println("man");
      new Person("woman"),  () ->  System.out.println("woman");
      new Person("child"),  () ->  System.out.println("child");        
      Null.class,           () ->  System.out.println("Null value "),
      Else.class,           () ->  System.out.println("Default value: " + data)
   );


   matches(data).as(
      Integer.class, i  -> { System.out.println(i * i); },
      Byte.class,    b  -> { System.out.println(b * b); },
      Long.class,    l  -> { System.out.println(l * l); },
      String.class,  s  -> { System.out.println(s * s); },
      Null.class,    () -> { System.out.println("Null value "); },
      Else.class,    () -> { System.out.println("Default value: " + data); }
   );

   matches(figure).as(
      Rectangle.class, (int w, int h) -> System.out.println("square: " + (w * h)),
      Circle.class,    (int r)        -> System.out.println("square: " + (2 * Math.PI * r)),
      Else.class,      ()             -> System.out.println("Default square: " + 0)
   );
```